# MSTest: "File extension specified '.dll' is not a valid test extension"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, mstest

I have a test project in VS2010, and I need to run the unit tests from command line. On one machine the following scenario works just fine:

1) Build the tests via "MSBuild test_project.csproj"

2) Run the tests via "MSTest /testcontainer:test_project.dll"

But on the other machine the 2nd step produced a weird error message, namely: "File extension specified '.dll' is not a valid test extension"

Any idea how to tackle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Check the registry on a PC that has Visual Studio 2010 installed: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\EnterpriseTools\QualityTools\TestTypes\`.

This contains all entries in regards to **allowed extensions** for MSTest. It would also probably be best to search for the test type keys (e.g. `{13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b}`) and making sure they exist (`.dll` must be in the list of allowed extensions)

Comment: Would really love an updated answer for this in VS2012/VS2015

Comment: For 2017 installation of VS 2017 Enterprise evaluation version allowed me to run mstest.exe with no issues

Answer (score 2):

If your 'other machine' is the build machine and there's no Visual Studio installed, you need to install Test Agent and Test controller (http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=1334).

Take a look at the post *Running tests in mstest without installing the VS IDE* (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/anutthara/archive/2009/12/16/running-tests-in-mstest-without-installing-the-vs-ide.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you are missing any of the following files it may cause this exception:

[image]

The files can be in the same directory or any configured directory. Configured locations can be found in **MSTest.exe.config** as an attribute on the **probing** element.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem with Visual Studio 2019, and it fact it was on a single computer.   For one user account, things worked fine, but for another account, I got this error.

I realized that for the second user account, I had never launched Visual Studio.

To resolve the problem, all I had to do was to log in as that second user account and launch Visual Studio, and then MSTest worked successfully afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I've read **[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/709288/visual-studio-2022-throws-error-with-file-extensio.html)** and it says "mstest is obsolete" now. Please use **[vstest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/vstest-console-options?view=vs-2019)** - I was facing same issue on GitHub Actions while running the workflow on self hosted runner.

Using VSTest issue has been fixed.

***Note:** Please follow the command line syntax carefully to avoid unexpected issues.*