# MTM run Telerik test case failed: File extension specified '.tstest' is not a valid test extension

Tags: tfs, telerik, microsoft-test-manager

Today we try to run telerik test case with MTM in BDT environment.

But it is failed with following error:

> Error adding test case [6603] to test run: File extension specified
>   '.tstest' is not a valid test extension.

Actions we have done:

1. Install telerik runtime on Environment

Manual run test case by mstest:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /testcontainer:.\Miscellaneous\testName.tstest
>
> Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 11.0.51106.1
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Loading .\Miscellaneous\testName.tstest...
>   .\Miscellaneous\testName.tstest Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.11.0, Version=11.0 .0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependenci es. The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fix this by install telerik runtime on tfs test controller.
and do following actions:

1. Unregister and re-register test controller
2. Unregister and re-register test agent
3. Restart test controller machine

Then error is gone. We got the error same as run command

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" testcontainer:.\Miscellaneous\testName.tstest

directly on environment.

> "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.11.0,
>   Version=11.0 .0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
>   or one of its dependenci es"

We referred following posts to resolve the error:

- http://www.telerik.com/forums/file-extension-specified-tstest-is-not-a-valid-test-extension/page/2
- http://www.telerik.com/forums/file-extension-specified-aii-is-not-a-valid-test-extension
- [MSTest: "File extension specified '.dll' is not a valid test extension"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501426/mstest-file-extension-specified-dll-is-not-a-valid-test-extension)
- http://docs.telerik.com/teststudio/user-guide/command-line-test-execution/mstest.aspx