# ".dll is not a valid test extension" when automate the coded ui test from command prompt

Tags: .net

My requriement is to automate the CodedUItest (developed by using visual studio 2017)in the machine(WindowsServer2012-R2 OS) where I should not download the Visual Studio and I should not use the network connection.So, I downloaded the visual studio Test Agent from https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/ in my local machine( windows7 OS) and copied the files from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TestAgent to my test machine.

Coded UITest case execution using command prompt(MSTest.exe) is working fine in my local machine,

whereas same batch file is showing error ".dll file is not the valid test extension" when executed in my test machine

Please help me to fix this. Your direction is most appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This answer should apply here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5495445/1592639